# method in a model to match ALL association values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model with a method where I am trying to "match all" tags a user selects. However, as soon as I select two tags in my app, and pass the params to the method below, it returns no results. One selection works fine.

As you can see I have a Style model, which has_many Tags through Tagizations. I want to "match all" the user selected tags, which my third line under the filter_with_params definition is my attempt at a proper query.

So, if I pass params[:t] = ["green", "yellow", "red"] to the filter method I'd only want to return the style(s) that has all three of those tags.

Here is a snippet from the model:

```
class Style < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tagizations, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :tags, :through => :tagizations

    def self.filter_with_params(params)
        scoped = self.where("styles.name != ''")
        scoped = scoped.includes(:tags)
        scoped = params[:t].inject(scoped){|memo, val| memo.where(:tags => {:name => val})} if params[:t]  
        scoped
    end
end
```

Here is a Gist with the development log output of two requests:

https://gist.github.com/jgrannas/6195528

**USING .TO_SQL**

SINGLE TAG (works):

```
Style.filter_with_params({:t => ["engagement"]}).to_sql
    => "SELECT \"styles\".* FROM \"styles\"  WHERE \"tags\".\"name\" = 'engagement' AND (styles.name != '')"
```

MULTIPLE TAGS (doesnt work)

```
Style.filter_with_params({:t => ["engagement", "Halo"]}).to_sql
     => "SELECT \"styles\".* FROM \"styles\"  WHERE \"tags\".\"name\" = 'engagement' AND \"tags\".\"name\" = 'Halo' AND (styles.name != '')
```

I am using postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

`WHERE "tags"."name" = 'engagement' AND "tags"."name" = 'Halo'`

The problem is that you are looking for something that has a **single** tag with **all** 3 names, which is impossible. What you want is something that has a tag for each name.

Not totally sure this will work, but try the following:

```
def self.filter_with_params(params)
    scoped = self.select("distinct styles.*, count(*) AS count")
    scoped = scoped.where("styles.name != ''")
    scoped = scoped.joins(:tags)
    if params[:t]
      scoped = scoped.where(tags: { name: params[:t] })
      scoped = scoped.group('styles.id')
      scoped = scoped.having("count = #{params[:t].size}")
    end
    scoped
end
```

What we're doing here essentially is we're building a table that has one row for **each** style-tag combination, but only for the tags in `params[:t]`. So, for example, we'll have a row for `style1 - tag1` and another row for `style1 - tag2`. Then we're grouping the rows by style id, so that we only get one record per unique style. But we're also counting how many rows we have in each group. We only want those records that had a row for **every** tag in the set of tags, so we discard the rest.

Note: the above code works for MySQL, but not for postgres. [The documentation for postgres `SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html) says:

> "An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but not in the WHERE or HAVING clauses; there you must write out the expression instead."

So we need `scoped = scoped.having("count(*) = #{params[:t].size}")`

Comment: This is how I originally had it. Like exactly like that. but it returns ANY style that has ANY of the tags. I need an AND, so if i request tags (green, yellow) i only want Styles that have BOTH those tags, not all Styles that have yellow, and all styles that have green. Make sense?

Comment: I see your edits... and right, i kind of figured that was the problem. Trying to match one tag name, to 2 or more tag names which will never return anything

Comment: I get this postgres error: 

PG::Error: ERROR:  column "count" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ement') AND (styles.name != '') GROUP BY id HAVING count = 1

Comment: Hmm, I used MySQL to test this. You added the `select` clause in the first line, right? That should define `count`.

Comment: Looking at the Postgres documentation, I see this: "An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but not in the WHERE or HAVING clauses; there you must write out the expression instead." So maybe try `scoped.having("count(*) = #{params[:t].size}")`

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 1: ...N ('engagement') AND (styles.name != '') GROUP BY id HAVING ...

Comment: try `.group('styles.id')` then

Comment: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "count" does not exist
LINE 1: ... AND (styles.name != '') GROUP BY styles.id HAVING count = 1

Comment: Heres what i got to work:
      scoped = scoped.having("count(*) = #{params[:t].size}") I will update your answer, if you approve it i'll mark it accepted

Comment: That's what I said 4 comments up :)

Answer (score 0):

I think i'd prefer injecting exists SQL clause for each tag. Output SQL should look like that

```
SELECT styles.* 
FROM styles
WHERE styles.name != ''
AND exists(SELECT * from tags where style_id = styles.id AND tags.name = 'red')
AND exists(SELECT * from tags where style_id = styles.id AND tags.name = 'green')
```

As far as i know, you would need to manually inject SQL to achieve that. therefore something like this :

```
def self.filter_with_params(params)
    scoped = self.where("styles.name != ''")
    scoped = scoped.includes(:tags)
    params[:t].each do |tag|
        scoped.where('EXISTS(select 1 FROM tags where tags.name = ? and tags.style_id = styles.id )', tag) 
    end
    scoped
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def self.with_tags *tags
  joins(:tags).where(:tags => {:name => tags}).group("#{self.table_name}.id").having("COUNT(DISTINCT tags.name) = ?", tags.length)
end
```